# can we write only return instead of return 0,1

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int SumEvennatural(int);
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter N:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("sum %d", SumEvennatural(n));
    getch();
    return 0;
}
int SumEvennatural(int n)
{
    int s = n * 2;
    if (n == 0)
        return ;              //i am asking here can i write 
    else
    {
        if (s % 2 == 0)
           return s + SumEvennatural(n - 1);
    }
}
```

i just need to know that is this a correct way to write return only istead of return 0 or 1 or any variable
this way i am getting warning [the warning i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO9cF.png)

Comment: If you declare a function to return a value, then it must explicitly return a value. The only exception is the [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) function where the final `return 0;` could be omitted and the compiler will implicitly add it (but this exception is only for the `main` function, and only for the ending `return 0;`).

Comment: On an unrelated note: Don't include `<conio.h>`. It's non-standard, and you don't even use anything from it in your code.

Comment: Which value do you `val` expect to contain after `int val = SumEvennatural(0);`?

Comment: You should treat all warnings as errors. Incidentally, please do not post or link images of errors. Why do you need to return "nothing"? What's wrong with `return 0;`?

Comment: You have not answered Jabberwockys nor n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.s questions to you, but I can see that you have commented answers below AFTER they posted the questions, so you were obviously online and looking at this page. Ignoring questions to your post is pretty rude when we are spending our free time to help you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The `<conio.h>` is likely for the `getch()` call.

Comment: Furthermore, don't post images of text

Comment: @IanAbbott The `getch` call was added in a later edit of the question. Still not good to use non-portable functions like that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “If you declare a function to return a value, then it must explicitly return a value”: That is not correct. The C standard permits a function with any return type to return by flowing to its closing `}`. If the return value is used, the behavior is not defined, but if the return value is not used, the behavior remains defined. This allows writing of, for example, getter-setter functions that either get (and return) some saved value or set (and do not return) a value depending on a command parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Assume that you could somehow "return" from `SumEvennatural()`. However, the code must have entered this final call from this line:

```
return s + SumEvennatural(n - 1);
```

So what value "X" should be used in `s + X` ?

Therefore when the function is declared to return `int` is must return an integer in all possible branches.

The workaround this issue is passing the actual sum as the reference (via a pointer) and update it only when a specific condition is met.

```
void SumEvennatural(int n, int *sum)
{
    int s = n * 2;
    if (n == 0)
        return ;
    else
    {
        if (s % 2 == 0) {
           // update the sum and enter the next recursive call
           *sum += s;
           SumEvennatural(n - 1, sum);
        }
    }
}

// usage:
int sum = 0;
SumEvennatural(n, &sum);
printf("sum %d", sum);
```

Comment: thanks dude i understand now thanks again

Comment: @HemantMaurya, see the update answer for workaround (if you really need it)

Comment: yes i really need that

Answer (score 0):

In `c` each function when declared also defines what is the return type of this function. In your case the return type is int because you declare it as `int SumEvennatural(int);`. A return without a value is only allowed in void functions, i.e. functions that do not return anything.

EDIT: A valid point made by Some programmer dude in the comments is that the return in the `main` function may be omitted and the compiler will implicitly add a `return 0`. Still a `return` in the main without an explicit value will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a function that is returning an integer.

This means that where you call the function you are expecting to be returned a value.

Now you ask whether you can return without giving a value.

You actually can (https://godbolt.org/z/MbxTPKxe7), that's why that's only a warning. The returned value is not defined to any fixed value. It is compiler and runtime dependent what value is returned in this case.

So you can see that it is not recommended because that's a source of errors.

Your goal should be to write warnings free code.

Comment: yes I wanna write warnings free code I will remember next time I do code I am just started and learning things

Comment: Re “It is compiler and runtime dependent what value is returned in this case”: When a program attempts to use the value of a function call and the function does not return a value, the behavior is not defined by the C standard (C 2018 6.9.1 12). It is not just that the returned value is not defined; the entire program behavior is not defined. For example, the program could crash.

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, you have to return an integer from your funcion, because of its prototype.
However, you can return e.g. -1, and use this value to check for error in the calling code, for exemple:

```
if (SumEvennatural(n) < 0) {
    printf("An error occured");
    exit(1); // Or whatever you wanna do in case of error
}
```

Another solution is to make your function return an 'exit status' (or nothing if you don't want to manage errors, and store your sum in a pointer, passed as paremeter, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70346464/9795359).